# NSPopover positions incorrectly when NSWindow frame is programmatically changed

Tags: nswindow, appkit, nspopover

I have a button in an `NSWindow` that brings up an `NSPopover` with:

```
popover = NSPopover()
popover?.behavior = .applicationDefined
popover?.contentViewController = self
let myDelegate = MyDelegate()
myDelegate.controller = self
popover?.delegate = myDelegate
popover?.show(relativeTo: hostingButton.bounds, of: hostingButton.superview!, preferredEdge: .minY)
```

This works great and I can drag the window around and resize it while the popover is open with zero problems.

The window, however, displays dynamic content and I have an option to keep it "compact" so to use the minimum height necessary for all of the current content to be shown.

When my code sets the `NSWindow`'s `frame` with `window.setFrame(newFrame, display: true)`, the popover moves to the other side of the screen. Its vertical alignment is perfect and matches the new window height, but its horizontal position is completely off.

The horizontal positioning on the **Screen** *appears* to be matching the x coordinate of the `hostingButton` within its superview, i.e. it sure looks like popover is using the x coordinate from the button's frame as a screen coordinate!?

Am I doing something wrong?

Is there a way of asking the popover, its hosting view, its superview, or its window to have another go at the positioning?

If not is there a way that I can manually move the popover window to the right place?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Should the popover follow `hostingButton` or its superview? Shouldn't it be `popover?.show(relativeTo: hostingButton.bounds, of: hostingButton, preferredEdge: .minY)` or `popover?.show(relativeTo: hostingButton.frame, of: hostingButton.superview!, preferredEdge: .minY)`?

Comment: Thanks. I tried various combinations including `NSRect.zero`, but I have re-tried your suggestions to no avail. I've found a completely unsatisfactory hack: sending `controller.popover?.positioningRect = NSRect.zero` with **asyncAfter**. This results in the popover snapping back from its position on the other side of the screen and is very ugly. The problem seems to be runloop related.

Comment: Which point should the popover follow and how does this point move when the window is resized?

Comment: The point that the popover is attached to is the center of an action button on the bottom left of the window. When the window resizes, the window stays the same width and its top left corner does not move, but its height changes, so the attachment point moves up or down. The popover's Y position changes correctly, but the X position is way off. Instead of being attached to a point approximately 60px from the left of the window (the center of the button), it gets placed approximately 60px from the left of the **screen**.